# Why using a point to point type(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *) rather than just a point type (NSProgress * __autoreleasing) in AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

In AFNetworking I find this function:

```
- (NSURLSessionUploadTask *)uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                         fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                         progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
                                completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

Here the progress type is NSProgress * __autoreleasing *.

I do not why here a point to point type is used rather than just a point type. The usage of progress parameter is as follows in this function:

```
if (progress) {
    *progress = delegate.uploadProgress;
}
```

In my mind, if declare:

```
NSProgress *progress = nil;
```

passing:

```
progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
```

and use it as:

```
*progress = delegate.uploadProgress;
```

is just the same as passing

```
progress:(__autoreleasing NSProgress *)progress
```

and use it as:

```
progress  = delegate.uploadProgress;
```

Could any one help explain why a point to point type is used here?

Comment: Using pass by reference with NSProgress indeed strange, since NSProgress has the concept of the "current" progress object. I would suggest looking at the commit and issue history surrounding this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of that parameter is to let the method pass back a pointer to an `NSProgress` object. To do that, the method needs to assign into the caller's variable.

Functions receive a copy of the passed value. If the parameter were just `__autoreleasing NSProgress*`, then the function would receive a copy of the passed pointer. Both the caller and the method would have variables containing a pointer to an `NSProgress` object, but they would be separate variables. When the method assigned to its variable using `progress  = delegate.uploadProgress;` it would only change its copy. The assignment would not affect the caller's variable.

When the parameter is `NSProgress * __autoreleasing *` and the caller passes `&callersProgress`, the function receives a copy of a pointer to the caller's variable. When the method uses `*progress` (as in `*progress = delegate.uploadProgress;`), it dereferences that pointer. That yields a reference to the caller's variable. So, the method is assigning to the caller's variable, not just a local variable.